# Prove: Least Squares Prediction Equation Contains Mean Point

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, predictive-models

$\newcommand{\szdp}[1]{\!\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\szdb}[1]{\!\left[#1\right]}$
**Problem Statement:** Show that the least squares prediction equation
$$\hat{y}=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_1+\cdots+\hat\beta_kx_k$$
passes through the point $(\overline{x}_1,\overline{x}_2,\dots,\overline{x}_k,\overline{y}).$

Note: This is Exercise 11.81 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer.

**My Work So Far:** What we need to do is show that
$$\overline{y}=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1\overline{x}_1+\hat\beta_2\overline{x}_2
+\cdots+\hat\beta_k\overline{x}_k.$$
Now if we set up the matrices
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&=\szdb{
\begin{matrix}
1&x_{11}&x_{21}&\cdots&x_{k1}\\
1&x_{12}&x_{22}&\cdots&x_{k2}\\
\vdots  &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
1&x_{1n}&x_{2n}&\cdots&x_{kn}
\end{matrix}}\\
\mathbf{a}&=\szdb{
\begin{matrix}
1\\ \overline{x}_1\\ \overline{x}_2\\ \vdots \\ \overline{x}_k
\end{matrix}
}\\
\mathbf{y}&=\szdb{
\begin{matrix}
y_1\\y_2\\ \vdots \\ y_n
\end{matrix}},
\end{align*}
then we know
${\hat\beta}=(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x})^{-1}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y},$
and we are asked to prove
$\overline{y}=\mathbf{a}^T\hat\beta.$ Here $n$ is the number of data points, and $k$ is the number of features.

**My Questions:** I have no idea where to go from here, or even whether this is the right approach to begin. What's a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One place to start would be to replace your $a^T$ vector with $\frac1n$ times a row vector of $n$ 1's times $x$.  This is just the matrix version of finding the means ($\bar{x}$) of the columns.  When you substitute that (and $\hat{\beta}$) into your last equation you will have a piece that computes means times the hat matrix times the y vector.  Look up the properties of the hat matrix and/or remember that $y_i = \hat{y_i} + \hat\epsilon_i$ and remember or look up what the mean of the observed residuals is to continue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to make sure I'm understanding, you're recommending 
$$\mathbf{a}^T=\frac1n[\underbrace{\begin{matrix}1&1&\dots&1\end{matrix}}_{n\times}]?$$

Comment: Or do you mean $$\mathbf{a}^T=\frac1n\left[
\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
1 &1 &1 &\dots &1
\end{matrix}}_{n\times}
\right]\mathbf{x}?$$

Comment: I can see that you meant the latter expression, with $\mathbf{x}$ in it. Now I have a new question: I can see that your suggestion allows me to get to $$\mathbf{a}'\hat\beta
=\frac1n\left[
\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
1 &1 &1 &\dots &1
\end{matrix}}_{n\times}
\right]Py.$$
But why should $\overline{y}=\overline{\hat{y}}?$ Oh, your last comment. Gotta follow it out!

Answer (score 4):

An alternate approach:

1. If the mean of all the $x$s was zero, the mean point would be $(0,\dots,0,\hat\beta_0)$.  The matrix $X^TX$ would be block diagonal, with a block for the intercept and a block for everything else, which will imply $\hat\beta_0=\bar y$. So the fitted (hyper)plane passes through the mean point.
2. Reparametrising $x_i\mapsto x_i-\bar x_i$ relabels the x axes but it doesn't change whether the fitted (hyper)plane goes through a point. So if the result holds when the $x$s have mean zero, it holds in general